# An application that determines an entered integer to be odd or even in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to the java language and have just learned basic stuff as of yet. I have to write an application that asks a user to enter an integer, and then display a statement that indicates whether an integer is even or odd. This is what I have done:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenOdd
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter an integer >> ");
      int num = input.nextInt();

      double divisibleByTwo = num % 2;

      if(divisibleByTwo == 0)
         System.out.println("The integer entered is even.");
      else
         System.out.println("The integer entered is odd.");   
   }
}
```

The above code works fine, but the software that grades my code requires my code to be in this format:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class EvenOdd
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      // accept user input and check if number is even or odd
   }
   public static boolean isEven(int number)
   {
      // check if number is even
   }
}
```

The following is my setup, but I have several mistakes in it, and am not really sure how to get going and have it work right. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class EvenOdd
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      // accept user input and check if number is even or odd
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter an integer >> ");
      int num = input.nextInt();

      isEven(num);

      boolean divisible;
      isDivisibleByTwo = divisible;

      if(divisible == true)
         System.out.println("The integer entered is even.");
      else
         System.out.println("The integer entered is odd.");   
   }
   public static boolean isEven(int number)
   {
      // check if number is even
      int remainderByTwo = number % 2;
      boolean isDivisbleByTwo = (remainderByTwo == 0);
      return isDivisibleByTwo; 
   }
}
```

Comment: What are your mistakes? Are you getting any errors? If so, what is the first one? And what line causes it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use return value from method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985402/how-to-use-return-value-from-method-in-java)

Comment: I suggest that you learn about local variables and return values. These seem to be the two critical concepts that you need to understand here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I was having a problem with the line isEven(num); -- as RAZ_Muh_Taz pointed out, it was a problem with not assigning values properly. RAZ_Muh_Taz's answer had me figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example you are assigning the variable correctly when you do

```
double divisibleByTwo = num % 2;
```

and then using that value that was returned you check

```
if(divisibleByTwo == 0)...
```

which returns true or false. However in the next sample of code you do

```
isEven(num); //NO asignment!!!!

boolean divisible; //defaults to false
isDivisibleByTwo = divisible;

if(divisible == true) //divisble will always be false
```

Since you never assign divisible to the value returned by isEven your if statement will always return false because the default value of boolean variables are false.

You need to assign the value returned by your isEven method call and then use that value like this

```
boolean isDivisibleByTwo = isEven(num);

if(isDivisibleByTwo)
   System.out.println("The integer entered is even.");
else
   System.out.println("The integer entered is odd.");
```

Or you can use the returned value of the isEven method without having to assign it to a variable like this

```
if(isEven(num))
   System.out.println("The integer entered is even.");
else
   System.out.println("The integer entered is odd.");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to overcomplicate things. You just need cleaner and simple code:

```
public class OddEven {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // accept user input and check if number is even or odd
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer >> ");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        boolean remainder = isEven(num);
        if (remainder == true)
            System.out.println("The integer entered is even.");
        else
            System.out.println("The integer entered is odd.");
    }

    public static boolean isEven(int number) {

        if (number % 2 == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to do all the calculation in the `isEven` method, your main method will only be used to get the number from the user and call the other method. No need to do calculations there.

In other words something like the following :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class EvenOdd
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      // Get the user input
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter an integer >> ");
      int num = input.nextInt();
      // Check if the input is correct ?

      // Call your method and check the return value
      if(isEven(num))
         System.out.println("The integer entered is even.");
      else
         System.out.println("The integer entered is odd.");   
   }

   // And then your method is good
   public static boolean isEven(int number)
   {
      // check if number is even
      return (number % 2) == 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an application that reads in two integers and determines and prints whether the first is a multiple of the second. For example, if the user inputs  15 and 3, the first number is a multiple of the second. If the user inputs 2 and 4, the first number is not a multiple of the second.

Comment: Hi, think that your solution is not answering the original question, the OP is asking about "a program to enter an integer" hence your suggestion about a program that reads two integers does not meet the requirements.